# do I need a lexer to disambiguate keywords? (boost::spirit)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm writing a parser for a little language similar to GLSL. I was just working on parsing  "in" and "out" variables, and noticed that my rule broke parsing of "int x;" presumably because "int" begins with "in". "float x;" parsed fine. The relevant rule is:

```
decl = -(lexeme["in"] | lexeme["out"]) >> type >> var >> (('(' >> arglist >> ')' >> block)
                                                          | ('=' >> expr >> ';')
                                                          | ';');
```

So do I need to tokenize first using lex? Or can I get away with just using Qi somehow?

Comment: Ah, derp. Just bumped into an old answer of mine that answers this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

You can manually assert keyword boundaries:

```
 in_kw = "in" >> !char_("A-Za-z_");
```

But that's tedious. You can also use `distinct[]` from the Spirit Repository: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/repository/example/qi/distinct.cpp

Comment: I'm having trouble getting that working (does't parse "in float x;"). Could it be that I can no longer use ascii::space as the skip parser?

Comment: @Taylor You didn't show enough code for me to assume skippers. Of course, you will need to lexemes as necessary. See also [this backgrounder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)